# Postgres, query the result of a subquery?

Tags: postgresql

I have data which is employee level which I aggregate daily, and then join back to a roster to get the name and manager name, etc. Is there a way to then aggregate this data (with the manager name) and join it back to the original data?

Up until this point works fine. I make one row per system_id per date. I join the system ID with a mapping table to get the Employee ID. I then join that to a roster table to get some Employee Information (including their supervisor name).

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT (system_id)
    FROM schema.fact_table
    WHERE report_date >= '2017-09-01') AS t1
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT report_date :: DATE
    FROM generate_series('2017-09-01' :: DATE , '2017-09-10' :: DATE , INTERVAL '1 day') report_date ) AS t2
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *
    FROM schema.dimension_table_1
    WHERE system_id IS NOT NULL
            AND expiration_date > '2017-09-01') AS t3
    ON t1.system_id = t3.system_id
        AND t2.report_date >= t3.effective_date
        AND t2.report_date <= t3.expiration_date
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *
    FROM schema.dimension_table_2
    WHERE expiration_date > '2017-09-01') AS t4
    ON t3.employee_id = t4.employee_id
        AND report_date >= t4.effective_date
        AND report_date <= t4.expiration_date
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT report_date AS report_date,
         system_id AS system_id,
         sum(stuff_count) AS stuff_count,

    FROM schema.fact_table_1
    WHERE report_date >= '2017-09-01'
    GROUP BY  report_date, avaya_id, source_database ) AS t5
    ON t2.report_date = t5.report_date
        AND t1.system_id = t5.system_id
```

I then want to add some columns which have the aggregated daily performance for the employee's team.

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT report_date,
         supervisor_employee_id,
         sum(stuff_count) AS supervisor_stuff_count,

    WHERE report_date = '2017-09-01'
    GROUP BY  report_date, supervisor_employee_id) AS t7
    ON supervisor_employee_id = supervisor_employee_id
        AND report_date = report_date
```

How can I achieve this? I need to somehow give an alias to the entire upper section (daily aggregated employee level data with the supervisor name), and then aggregate that alias on the date + supervisor_id_column instead. I just couldn't get it to work right.

Comment: Your last subquery alias is `t7`  but you use `supervisor_employee_id` without alias? You need `ON T7.supervisor_employee_id = SOMETHING.supervisor_employee_id`

Comment: Sorry, yeah. I had attempted to add aliases but I failed. That is just because I copied and pasted some stuff and forgot to remove it. Ignore my aliases in that final section.

Comment: mmmm I cant ignore that. If you put correct alias the query should work. But your question is too long I cant do all debug for you.   Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `DISTINCT (system_id)` is **exactly** the same thing as `DISTINCT system_id`

Comment: I originally wrapped my entire first section in (SELECT * FROM ... AS t6). So the top section was t6 and the bottom query was labeled as t7). I kept getting an error that t6 didn't exist though, so I wasn't sure that it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to somehow give an alias to the entire upper section (daily
>   aggregated employee level data with the supervisor name)

Use **WITH** ([Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)) which enable you to "reuse" a query by reference to an alias given to the query e.g.

```
WITH myCTE as (
....
)
select *
from myCTE
```

Aggregations can be performed in or after the CTE as needed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this but it made it so much easier. I don't know what my issue was before.. perhaps parenthesis or something small. But this cleaned it all up and I am a fan. Thanks